# LINQ Left Join and GroupBy

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

Let say I have this SQL Query:

```
SELECT 
    PromotionSlot.StaffFName, 
    SUM(PromotionSlot.Max_Occupancy) AS TOTAL,
    SUM(DISTINCT(Booking.Quantity)) AS Occupied
From PromotionSlot 
LEFT JOIN Booking
ON PromotionSlot.StaffID=Booking.StaffID
GROUP BY  PromotionSlot.StaffFName
```

Result:

```
|StaffFName    |TOTAL    |Occupied|
-----------------------------------
|Jason         |13       |1       |
|John Doe      |9        |0       |      
|Marry Jane    |7        |2       |
```

This is my DB Table:

```
PromotionSlot TABLE: ID(PK),Max_Occupancy,StaffFName..., StaffID(FK)
Booking TABLE: ID(PK), Quantity...,StaffID(FK)
```

How can I translate it into LINQ? This is my attempt:

```
var staffData = 
    (from ps in dc.PromotionSlots
     join b in dc.Bookings on ps.StaffID = b.StaffID
     group ps by ps.StaffFName into NewGroup
     select new dataView
     {
         StaffFName = NewGroup.Key,
         Total = NewGroup.Sum(a => a.Max_Occupancy),

         //problem:
         //Occupied = NewGroup.Sum(b => b.Quantity)
     }
```

Plan to have `Occupied = NewGroup.Sum(b => b.Quantity)` but when I try to point the `b` to the `quantity` column from `Booking` table it shows error(red-line) and I think the problems comes from `group ps by ps.StaffFName into NewGroup` makes it available for `PromotionSlot` table instead of `Booking` table. But I totally have no idea how to solve this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your `SQL` query, what you need is take `Distinct` quanties and `Sum` them.

```
var staffData = 
    (from ps in dc.PromotionSlots
     join b in dc.Bookings on ps.StaffID = b.StaffID into slots
     from slot in slots.DefaultIfEmpty()
     group new {ps, slot} by ps.StaffFName into NewGroup
     select new dataView
     {
         StaffFName = NewGroup.Key,
         Total = NewGroup.Sum(a => a.ps!=null? a.ps.Max_Occupancy: 0),

         //problem:
         Occupied = NewGroup.Select(x=>x.slot.Quantity).Distinct().Sum()
     }
```

Comment: when try to type in `x => x.<COLUMN>` it still shows the `ps` table column only instead of `b` table.

Comment: You need to group both entities `group new {ps, b} by ps.StaffFName into NewGroup`.

Comment: @J4X please check now.

Comment: Now I able to search two table in the `select new`

Comment: It's still not correct.  The first `Sum` should use a lambda like `a => a.ps.Max_Coccupancy` and the second should have `x => x.b.Quantity`.

Comment: @juharr yes, noted. Suppose to be `a =>a.ps.Max_Occupancy`

Comment: You should now be grouping `slot` instead of `b`.

Comment: ahh ...I missed it, thanks @juharr . Will update it.

Comment: Thank You so much @HariPrasad, you just made my day!

Comment: Thanks @juharr too!